# Why isn't my code reading the correct integers from a file?

Tags: c

So after playing a little bit with Craig Estey's answer, I managed to get the following piece of code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 


int main(int argc,char **argv){
    char *filename = argv[1];
    if(filename == NULL) {
        printf("Please specify a filename.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fi = fopen(filename,"r");
    printf("Finding size...\n");
    int size = 0;
    while(fscanf(fi,"%*d") != -1) size++;
    rewind(fi);
    int numbers[size];
    while(fscanf(fi,"%d",&numbers[size]) != 1);
    fclose(fi);
    printf("Size of array: %d\n\n", size);
    int idx=0,idx2=1,idx3=1,idx4=1;
    printf("Elements: \n");
    while (idx < size){
        printf("%d\n",numbers[idx]);
        idx++;
    }
    int maximum = numbers[0];
    while (idx2 < size){
            if (numbers[idx2] > maximum){
                maximum  = numbers[idx2];
        }
        idx2++;
    }
    printf("\nMax: %d\n",maximum);
    int minimum = numbers[0];
    while (idx3 < size){
            if (numbers[idx3] < minimum){
                minimum  = numbers[idx3];
        }
        idx3++;
    }
    printf("Min: %d\n",minimum);
    int sum = numbers[0];
    while (idx4 < size){
        sum = sum + numbers[idx4];
        idx4++;
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n",sum);
}
```

Problem is, now it executes without halting, but still doesn't provide the right answer. My 'abcd.txt' file contains the following numbers:

5564

4324

863

98743

However, my result after executing reader.c is:

```
./reader abcd.txt
Finding size...
Size of array: 4

Elements: 
0
0
1384783917
32713

Max: 1384783917
Min: 0
Total: 1384816630
```

Why is that, now? I cannot find why is it different than in the answer below. If I execute the exact code in the answer, it **does** return the right answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `void main (char *filename)` isn’t a correct signature for `main` – you should have learned `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Might also want to read [ask]

Comment: please show how you call your program and in which directory your `abcd.txt` resides.

Comment: Ry- found [at least] your initial problem. Define `main` as `int main(int argc,char **argv)` and then do `fopen(argv[1],"r")`. As you've defined `main`, your `filename` pointer will be given [silently] a value of 0x02 [or some other worse/garbage value] which causes a segfault due to an invalid pointer dereference.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't ask properly, I tried to follow all the steps, and it even didn't let me add an image of the expected result because I didn't have enough "reputation". tell me what do I miss and I will try to add that. Also thanks for the tip on the main, I am quite bad at this.

Regarding how do I call the program. With filename:
`gcc -o reader ./reader.c`
`./reader abcd.txt`

(I tried also /abcd.txt or "abcd.txt" or "/abcd.txt")
With abcd.txt directly in the code:
`./reader`

abcd.txt is obviously in the same folder as this file (reader).

Comment: You should _edit_ your question and post your sample input file in a separate code block. This allows us to download, compile, link, and run your program with enough input to reproduce your problem [_beyond_ the fix for the segfault]. Note that you should do: `char *filename = argv[1];` to handle all places where `filename` is used. Note that this is a quick fix because it doesn't handle the case where the program argument is omitted (e.g. `argc` is 1 and `argv[1] == NULL`)

Comment: You probably don't need to post your whole program.  Just post the minimal snippet that reproduces the failure.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and use a debugger.

Comment: I now finally managed to edit my original question, changing it according to Ry's and Craig's suggestions, and added a sample of how my number file abcd.txt could look like. Also, I write my code on a blank reader.c text document, maybe that also sets me back. Eventually I will have to change to a proper compiler.

Comment: `numbers[idx] = (int *) p_data;` perhaps you meant `numbers[idx] = *(int *) p_data;`? The compiler will not compile the original statement.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read integers from a binary file, but the name of the file with the .txt extension suggests that it is a text file. (Also, why do you want to allocate `p_data` on the heap, and separately every time, why not just `int data;` and read to `&data`?)

Comment: why are you using such low level io operations, why not fopen etc

Comment: @bruceg OP's program is pretty minimal as it is [at 94 lines and 2143 chars, it's well within MCVE guidelines]. At OP's stage of skill/development, trying to cut it down further would probably produce greater issues for him and us. There have been cases where an OP reduces their program,at the direction of a responder, and clips out essential code that has to be added back.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS of warning messages, several of which are critical.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ) for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same things

Comment: OT: never access beyond `argv[0]`  with out first checking `argc` to assure the desired command line argument was actually entered by the user.  If the desired number of command line arguments was not entered, then output a USAGE statement to `stderr`, similar to: `fprintf( stderr,  "USAGE: %s filename\n", argv[0] );` and then calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: You're confusing reading numbers as ASCII text and decoding them. Also, you're trying to store an `int` pointer into an `int` array (i.e. `numbers`). Not the same thing. Also, you're using `open` and `read` when `fopen` and either `scanf` or `fgets` with `strtok` and/or `strtol` is a better choice.

Comment: In programming it is best to keep things simple. IOW when you read from a text file use fgets into a buffer and then process that buffer. while (fscanf(... (!=-1) makes me cringe. Start by reading a text file line by line using `fgets() ` then use `sscanf` or `strtok` a to process the contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

You can't do: `printf(numbers[idx2]);` (i.e. the first argument has to be a format string). So, do: `printf("%d\n",numbers[idx2]);`

Doing `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)` does *not* give an accurate count of the number *actually* filled in. It gives the *maximum* which will have garbage values at the end.

Because, there were so many errors, I couldn't list them all. I had to completely refactor your code. Just compare it *in detail* to yours to see the difference. You'll learn much more and more quickly than trying to patch what you already have.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long int
findSize(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("findSize: unable to open file '%s' -- %s\n",
            filename,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long int res = ftell(fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return res;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *filename = argv[1];
    if (filename == NULL) {
        printf("please specify a filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("findSize\n");
    int numbers[findSize(filename)];

    printf("scanf\n");
    FILE *fi = fopen(filename,"r");
    int size = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (fscanf(fi,"%d",&numbers[size]) != 1)
            break;
        printf("scanf: %d\n",numbers[size]);
        ++size;
    }
    fclose(fi);

    printf("size: %d\n",size);
    for (int idx2 = 0;  idx2 < size;  ++idx2)
        printf("%d\n",numbers[idx2]);

    int maximum = numbers[0];
    for (int idx3 = 1;  idx3 < size;  ++idx3) {
        if (numbers[idx3] > maximum)
            maximum = numbers[idx3];
    }
    printf("Max: %d\n", maximum);

    int minimum = numbers[0];
    for (int idx4 = 1;  idx4 < size;  ++idx4) {
        if (numbers[idx4] < minimum)
            minimum = numbers[idx4];
    }
    printf("Min: %d\n", minimum);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int idx5 = 0;  idx5 < size;  ++idx5)
        sum = sum + numbers[idx5];
    printf("Total: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> First of all, thanks a lot for your work. Looking at your code (I cannot call it anymore my code as it's completely different)

Yes, it was intended as a guide for you to write/rewrite your own code, which you've done.

> I see that the findSize function is mostly irrelevant.

It is technically correct, but would allocate [much] more space than was needed.

> I tried to put another fscanf instead of calling a findSize function, but I don't know how this function works exactly.

Good for you in figuring out this alternate sizing algorithm.

> Let me see if I get it: If there is a third argument, it stores each read element into the third argument (which should be a variable). But if there is no third element, and you put an * in the second argument, it doesn't store the read elements anywhere. Am I right?

Believe it or not, I don't use `fscanf` too much as it can be slow, so I'm not familiar with some of the more esoteric options. I've tested your new sizing loop and it appears to work, so I think your analysis may be correct.

Also, we could simply introduce an extra scalar `int` variable and do:

```
int size = 0;
while (1) {
    int val;
    if (fscanf(fi,"%d",&val) != 1)
        break;
    ++size;
}
```

---

However, you're actual second `fscanf` loop that is used to read in the numbers will *not* work:

```
while (fscanf(fi, "%d", &numbers[size]) != 1);
```

This puts *all* numbers in the *same* index, namely `size`, which is one *beyond* the end of the `numbers` array, so this is undefined behavior.

Also, the loop condition is reversed from what it should be, so only *one* number would be filled in.

To fix this, we need an additional index variable and need to change the sense of the `while` loop:

```
int idx0 = 0;
while (fscanf(fi, "%d", &numbers[idx0]) == 1)
    ++idx0;
```

After this change, the rest of your updated code [min/max/sum] works fine.

---

Some notes on style:

As you noticed, *my* original posted code was a bit different (e.g. replacing `while` loops with `for` loops).

But, one thing I *didn't* do was reuse the index variable. That is, there isn't a need to have separate ones for each loop. They could all be changed to a single `idx` variable.

Using different symbols isn't wrong, and *can* add to clarity. But, `idx`, `idx1`, `idx2` aren't as descriptive as they could be.

If you'd like to keep separate variables, I'd suggest more descriptive names such as: `inpidx`, `minidx`, `maxidx`, and `sumidx`

Comment: Why the DV? The guidelines for DV on SO are an answer that is _egregiously_ wrong.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your work. Looking at your code (I cannot call it anymore my code as it's completely different) I see that the findSize function is mostly irrelevant. I tried to put another fscanf instead of calling a findSize function, but I don't know how this function works exactly. Let me see if I get it:
If there is a third argument, it stores each read element into the third argument (which should be a variable). But if there is no third element, and you put an * in the second argument, it doesn't store the read elements anywhere. Am I right?

(continuation below)

Comment: Thanks! These 2 errors (reversing the loop condition and forgetting to reset size before the loop and increase inside the loop) were quite embarassing. Now it works perfectly. The while are there because for some reason, if I use 'for', the console spits a warning saying 'You need to compile in C99 mode'. I obviously can add -std=c99 to the end, but I preferred to just use whiles instead (I don't like warnings).
Thanks again!

Comment: @CraigEstey it’s probably a punishment down vote. Someone’s way of saying don’t answer out of scope questions. Personally if people want to put in the effort to answers these question, more power to them.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks. The DV came early (before the update section). I suspect it _was_ punishment--from the "don't answer homework questions" camp [which I'm _not_ a member of]. IMO, when a question is so far away, merely "hints" aren't going to help an OP much. Normally, I try to remain [somewhat] faithful to an OP's code, give an explanation of errors, annotate the code with the bugs [and fixes] and sometimes present a second cleaned up version. A number of OPs like this approach. And, here, OP was able to take my version as a guide to fixing his own code [just what I had hoped for].